# Accessing previously returned value from each?

Tags: c#, excel, lambda, powerquery, m

In C# I can write something like this:

```cs
int? valueForNewColumeInPreviousRecord = null;

myTable.AddColumn("New Column Name", (record) => {
                                        int newColumeValue;
                                        newColumeValue = valueForNewColumeInPreviousRecord.HasValue ?
                                                            valueForNewColumeInPreviousRecord.Value + record.SomeOtherValue : 
                                                            record.SomeOtherValue;

                                        valueForNewColumeInPreviousRecord = newColumeValue;

                                        return newColumeValue;
                                    } + 42);
```

**NOTE:** The `+ 42` part, which makes it impossible to read/get/access the last returned value from any record in the table.

How would I go about doing this in Power Query?
Or is there a completely different way of doing this kind of stuff there?

I'm not interested in actually adding a new column to a table, but the actual concept of accessing previously returned/calculated data from a lambda/each, and if possible, how you can store data in a variable.

The table thing is just a great concrete example where you might want to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but this looks pretty similar to what functions like [List.Accumulate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-accumulate) and [List.Generate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-generate) allow you to do.

These are pretty similar to loops where you initialize and update values as you iterate through a list.

Comment: so how would you access/use the previous result to a call to List.Accumulate in the current call to it?

Comment: Imagine you are calling Table.AddColumn, where the third parameter is a function which should return the value for the added column for the current record. Each call to this function is stateless in regards to earlier calls to previous records, all you get is the current record as an argument. So the List functions can't really be used here, and you need a method to store and access the last result of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but with big tables is very slow. Let's see it with a running total example.

Take a table named "Source" with a "Values" column with numbers to accumulate.

First thing to do is to add an index column.

```
Indexed = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index"),
```

Then, and following your question, a new column named "RunTot" is added. Each value of this new column will be the number from "Values" of this row plus the previous running total ("RunTot"). The trick is the "@" symbol before this part "@Output[RunTot]{[Index]-1}", this way you are calling the previous element of the column you are constructing.

"try ... otherwise" is just a way to avoid the error you get when you pass a negative index to a list.

Last, "Table.Buffer" is a way to speed up thinks a bit.

```
Output = Table.Buffer(Table.AddColumn(Indexed, "RunTot", each [Values] + (try @Output[RunTot]{[Index]-1} otherwise 0)))
```

But as Alexis propose, it's much better the "List.Generat" approach. This is a running total function using List.Generate:

```
fnListGenerateRunningTotal = (Input as list) as list => 
List.Generate( 
        ()=> [Total = Input{0}, Counter = 0],
        each [Counter] < List.Count(Input),
        each [Total = Input{Counter} + [Total], Counter = [Counter] + 1],
        each [Total]
    )
```

Comment: i think you missed this part "I'm not interested in actually adding a new column to a table, but the actual concept of accessing previously returned/calculated data from a lambda/each, and if possible, how you can store data in a variable."

Comment: This is an excerpt from Ben Gribaudo's blog: 

"In order for an expression to reference the identifier it’s assigned to, simply prepend an @ in front of the reference. Self-referencing is handy when defining recursive functions".

In my example, I used "@Output[RunTot]{[Index]-1}". The definition of the table "Output" contains a (self) reference to the table itself, in fact to the new column "RunTot" you are creating wiht the Table.AddColumn function. This way you can access the previous returned value using an index. I used a table but the same can be applied to lists or records.

Comment: You are not really reading/accessing the previously returned value, instead you are reading a value stored in a previous record by using an added index column. There is no guarantee that what you returned from your previous calculation is what is stored in the record, there could be other calculations/operations done outside your function which affect the value stored in the record. Also you can't assume you have any control over the table and able to add an index column to it.

Comment: In M, it’s not possible to change a variable once its value has been evaluated.